# Implicit value not found in method to method call

Tags: scala

I'm trying to add a helper method to a config library by using `implicit` classes and type classes. However, I am extremely new to Scala (1 week) and have been unable to find out why the following code issues a compile error (I provide the working solution in a comment in the code)

Simplification of the third party package:

```
package pkg

class Config {
  def hasPath(path: String) = { false }
  def getString(path: String) = { "str" }
  def getInt(path: String) = { 7 }
  def getDouble(path: String) = { 3.14d }
}
```

And my example file:

```
import pkg._

object Helpers {

  trait Extractor[T] {
    def extract(cfg: Config, path: String): T
  }

  object Extractor {

    implicit object IntExtractor extends Extractor[Int] {
      def extract(cfg: Config, path: String) = {
        99
      }
    }

  }

  implicit class BetterConfig(cfg: Config) {

    def extract[T](path: String)(implicit extractor: Extractor[T]): T = {
      extractor.extract(cfg, path)
    }

    // This example works if I add the implicit parameter:
    // (implicit extractor: Extractor[T])
    def extract[T](path: String, default: T): T = {
      if ( cfg.hasPath(path) ) {
        extract[T](path)
        //        ^ error here
      } else { 
        default
      }
    }
  }
}


object Demo extends App {

  import Helpers._

  val cfg = new Config
  val x = cfg.extract("foo", 3)

  println(s"x: ${x}")
}
```

This code gives the error `could not find implicit value for parameter extractor: Helpers.Extractor[T]`

Why can't the implicit value be found when calling `extract(path)` from within `extract(path, default)`? My understanding of the scoping rules or resolving the implicit, is wrong. I would have thought that when the call to `extract(path)` was made from within `extract(path, default)`, the implicit would still be resolved from the companion object of `Extractor`.

I have tried this with Scala 2.10.6 and 2.11.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call needs an implicit `Extractor[T]`, where nothing is known about `T`. It *would* be resolved from the companion object, if there was one, but there is no such method there.

Imagine it worked. Then

```
val cfg = new Config
val x = cfg.extract[String]("foo", "")
```

should also compile. But how would it work without an implicit `Extractor[String]` anywhere?

Comment: At what point does the compiler try to work out what T is? I guess I have wrongly thought it would know that T is Int because that is the type of the integer literal '3'. I can totally see that the String version would not work, because I do not provide an implementation of Extractor[String] (in this example at least).

Comment: When the compiler is looking at `def extract[T](path: String, default: T): T`, it _doesn't_ try to work out what `T` is at all: your definition must work for _all_ `T`.

Comment: It figures out that `T` is `Int` for this specific call when looking at `cfg.extract("foo", 3)`, but that's separate; you already have an error in the definition, even if you never called this method at all.

Comment: Ah! OK. The tutorials etc. I have been reading do not really explain when the compiler deals with generic types. I have a C++ background and am used to the compiler only really attempting to resolve related function calls when the generic function (template) is used. I removed the `cfg.extract("foo", 3)` call from my code and it does not compile, as you said. So now I understand what's happening, thanks!